# Progress Bar doesn't move

Tags: c++, windows, mfc

I need such logic:

```
ShowProgressBar();

Sleep(1000); //---> do here some work 

HideProgressBar();

MessageBoxW(_T("Wait"), _T("Title"), MB_OK);

ShowProgressBar();

Sleep(1000); //---> do here some work

HideProgressBar();
```

I call this code in separate thread (not main GUI thread). I got normal dialog window but it's progress bar is immobilized:

[image]

Then:

[image]

And then:
[image]

This is ShowProgressBar function:

```
progressBarWindow = new Progress(this);

if (!progressBarWindow->Create(IDD_PROGRESSBAR, this))
{
    AfxMessageBox(TEXT("BAD PROGRESS BAR"));
    return;
}
if(!progressBarWindow->ShowWindow(SW_SHOWNA))
{
    AfxMessageBox(TEXT("BAD PROGRESS BAR"));
    return;
}   

this->BeginModalState();
```

This is HideProgressBar implementation:

```
progressBarWindow->EndDialog(0);
this->EndModalState();
```

Progress - is a class of Progress Bar dialog window. It is absolutely standart, has progress bar element with marque setting:

```
m_ProgressBar.SetMarquee(TRUE, 10)
```

in OnInitDialog function

Comment: It is not recommended to update UI from separate thread. The main thread is responsible for updating UI.

Comment: Impossible to answer the question given the incomplete information available. We need a [mcve] to make a call here.

Comment: @IInspectable what additional info do you need? I can provide all the necessary...

Comment: A [mcve].......

Answer (score 2):

Windows have thread affinity.

You’re calling progressBarWindow->Create() on a background thread. The progress bar now lives in your background thread, and expects the thread to have a message pump.

It doesn’t matter it’s parent window belongs to another thread, Windows is OK doing multi-threaded GUI. However you’re not OK. You’re sleeping with Sleep(1000), so the thread ain’t processing windows messages. I think that’s why no GUI updates in your app.

For most applications, the right way to do threading — do all the GUI in the main thread. Even progress bars logically related to the background threads should still be created in the main GUI thread.

To fix, create all your GUI in the main GUI thread, and only use your separate thread for computations, or IO, or whatever else your work is.

P.S. If your next question going to be “But how to notify the GUI thread when my background thread needs to change progress, or completes its job?” — one method is custom windows messages.

For example, you can send `WM_USER + 11` to some window (e.g. to your Progress dialog) when your thread finishes the processing, and `WM_USER + 12` when your thread needs to update the progress bar position, passing progress position in lParam or wParam. The message handler will be called in the main thread, where you can update progress, or close the progress popup, or do anything else with your GUI.

Comment: Good answer, but why `WM_USER + 11` and not `WM_USER + 537` :) OK, if speaking seriously, even though `WM_USER` + `0x7FFF` message range could be "kinda" OK to use, to be safe I'd stick with the `WM_APP` message range for this purpose. `WM_USER` range [may be used](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/winmsg/wm-user) by some common control classes that could lead to weird bugs.

Comment: @c00000fd MSDN documents these private messages used by built-in classes. In case of dialogs, only 3 private messages are used, `WM_USER+0` to `+2`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/dlgbox/dialog-box-messages

Comment: Well, why deal with this at all when you can use a safe `WM_APP` range instead?